# Suppressing page numbers in "exam" document class

Tags: page-numbering, exam

I'm using the `exam` class like this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] Who's buried in Grant's tomb?
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Now I try to remove page numbers using `\pagenumbering{gobble}`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] Who's buried in Grant's tomb?
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

And I get this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5   \question[1]
                   Who's buried in Grant's tomb?
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

1. Why does this happen?
2. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should I do to fix it?

You should use either `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\cfoot{}`.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum} % provides filler text
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] Who's buried in Grant's tomb?
  \lipsum[1-30] % 3+ pages of filler text
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

> Why does this happen?

I'm not privy to the deep reasons for *why* the designer(s) of this document class made various design choices. All I can offer is a *what is going on* explanation, in terms of LaTeX code. The document class has a feature called an "incomplete question". In order to determine whether or not a given question may be incomplete, the code compares the number of the current page with the final page number of the document. If somebody -- e.g., you -- executes `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, no page numbers are available to carry out this comparison, and all the TeX program can do is crash with the 'weird error' exception.

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't explain why `\pagenumbering{gobble}` doesn't work.

Comment: @bariumbitmap -- I've posted an addendum to address your "why" question.